# Can directional derivatives be written as linear combination of partial derivatives even if f is not differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ linearly independent vectors such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}$ exists.

I know if f is differentiable then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_i}$=$\nabla f\cdot v$ so the directional derivative of f can be expressed as a linear combination of the partial derivatives.

If f is not differentiable:

1) $\nabla f$ exists ?

2) If $\nabla f$ exists ,can we express the directional derivatives as a linear combination of the partial derivatives?

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla f(x)$? If $f$ is not differentiable at $x$ then the gradient does not exist at $x$ and vice versa.

Comment: There are cases where all of the partial derivatives exists and f is still not differentiable. Thats what I meant.

Comment: @copper.hat $\nabla f(x)$ can exist even if $f$ is not differentiable at $x.$

Comment: $\nabla f(x)$ is just the element corresponding to $Df(x)$ that the Riesz representation theorem guarantees in a Hilbert space, so they are essentially the same.

Comment: @copper.hat: But existence of $Df(x)$ is not sufficient to give differentiability.

Comment: @TedShifrin: The Fréchet derivative? Perhaps I am used to different notation?

Comment: The matrix of partial derivatives may well exist even if the function isn't differentiable. As in the examples I gave below.

Comment: I realize that, I was using $Df(x)$ for the Fréchet derivative, not the matrix of partials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many examples of functions — even *discontinuous* functions — that have all partial derivatives but for which that linearity formula fails. You can find many of them littered around in questions on this site.  But here are a few. Set $f(0,0) = 0$ and for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ take
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} \\
f(x,y) &= \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} \\
f(x,y) &= \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}
\end{align*}
Find the gradient vector (hint: they'll all be $0$) at the origin, and compute the various directional derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I`ve tried sevral different directional derivatives and could not find a unit vector where the directional derivative at (0,0) exists and different than 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, for the examples I gave you, you should find nonzero directional derivatives in all directions except the coordinate directions.

Comment: I must be wrong with the limits calculations then, since I`m still new to this topic. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @Sar: Try doing the directional derivative in the direction $\vec v = (1,1)$, using the limit definition. You look at $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t,t)-f(0,0)}t,$$ right? What do you get in these three examples? (Oh, and, by the way, the first two examples are discontinuous, but the third example is continuous.)

Comment: Yes now I can see it . Thank you.

Comment: You have to consider $v=(1,1)/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides: No, that's not true, although in most standard calculus books the vector is supposed to be a unit vector. In fact, you can define the directional derivative $D_{\vec v}f(a)$ in the direction of any vector $\vec v$, and $D_{c\vec v}f(a) = c D_{\vec v}f(a)$ for any scalar $c$. When $f$ is differentiable at $a$, the quantity $D_{\vec v}f(a)$ then becomes a linear function of $\vec v$.

Answer (score 0):

Some other examples:

Let  $f(x) = 0 $ on the axes, but $1$ everywhere else. Then the partials along the axes exist at the origin but the function is not continuous at the origin.

Let $A = \{ (r \cos t, r \sin t)  | 0 < t \le 2 \pi, 0 \le r  \le t\}$ and $f=1_A$. Then the directional derivative $df(0,h) = 0$ for all directions $h$, but $f$ is not continuous at the origin.

The point of the last example is a function where the directional derivative
can be written as a linear combination of the partial derivatives but the
function is not continuous (and hence not differentiable) at the point.